# Publish ASP NET Core With Clean Achitecture

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, publish, web-hosting, clean-architecture

I developed a project with .NET Core 6 using Clean Architecture, published it in GIT and implemented it in Azure on a free Linux server.

[CashFlowMJV on GIT](https://github.com/EduSpada/CashFlowMJV)
[CashFlowMJV on Azure](https://cashflowmjv.azurewebsites.net/)

As the implementation in Azure was automatic, I am not sure how the files of each layer published inside the server are arranged.

I have a VPS where I installed the Plesk Obsidian administrative panel, I configured the .NET Toolkit correctly. I created a simple webapp and ran the following command:

`dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64`

The command generated the directory "\bin\Release\net6.0\linux-x64\publish" inside the project, I copied the files and moved them to "httpdocs" and pointed the initial file as "webapp.dll". The test project worked perfectly.

But I can't deploy my project with Clean Architecture on that server, I don't know how the folders and files should look as each layer generates a different publish directory. Each layer of the system is a .NET Core subproject, where:

- CashFlowMvc.Domain - classlib
- CashFlowMvc.Application - classlib
- CashFlowMvc.Domain.Tests - xUnit Test Project
- CashFlowMvc.Infra.Data - classlib
- CashFlowMvc.Infra.IoC - classlib
- CashFlowMvc.WebUI - webapp

How would the publish structure look in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening, this morning I identified that in Azure, where I first published the project, they had exactly the same files as the publish of the WebUI project, that's why when I run the command:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-x64
```

He already works on top of project dependencies.

My problem was how the environment variable is saved in the .NET Toolkit of Plesk for Linux, apparently when the server is Windows it has the option to save the specific connectionString variable and in Linux Plesk does not provide this type of configuration, I did a test inserting the connectionString directly into "appsettings.json" and it worked, but as this is not secure, I made the following change in the Infra.IoC project:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services,
                                                            IConfiguration configuration)
         {
             services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                 {
                     string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MysqlConnectionString");
                     options.UseMySql(connectionString,
                                     ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString));
                 }
             );
```

And so I saved the environment variable normally, I copied the publish files only from the WebUI project and it was a success. For those who are going to do it in Azure, there is no need, but it is more expensive to maintain, so here's the tip!

Eduardo Rodrigo Spada